# UIView isFirstResponder method always return no

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

In my viewController viewDidload() method  isFirstResponder always giving false value. Here is the 
code

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSLog(@"is first responder : %i", [self.view isFirstResponder]);
}
```

Can someone please help why this happening?

Comment: Have u tried this in viewDidAppear?

Comment: Yes, i tried , but it always return no.

Answer (score 0):

Subclasses can override this method to update state or perform some action such as highlighting 
  the selection.

A responder object only becomes the first responder if the current responder can resign first-
  responder status (canResignFirstResponder) and the new responder can become first responder.

You may call this method to make a responder object such as a view the first responder. However, 
  you should only call it on that view if it is part of a view hierarchy. If the view’s window 
  property holds a UIWindow object, it has been installed in a view hierarchy; if it returns nil, 
  the view is detached from any hierarchy.

[Here is Apple doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIResponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: So when a ViewController loaded, isn't it's view  is firstResponder? if not then which is the first responder in this case?

Comment: in that case UIWindow is first responder

Comment: Try adding this line in your app delegate if your this view is your first view [self.window addSubview: yourFirstView]; before calling becomeFirstResponder.

Comment: In the app Delegate currently it is like-    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;  So No way to make view Controller's view as a firstResponder without adding as a subview?

Comment: put the delegate method

- (BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder
{
    return YES;
}
and call it on your viewDid load     [self canBecomeFirstResponder];...i never try but may it work for you try this